# Bitcoin Cold Storage Question

Tags: bitcoin-core, coldstorage

I am ready to put some of my BTC holdings into a couple different cold storage wallets.  I went through the process already moving around a few mBits as tests, created the keys on an offline PC, sent real funds, then ran an import in bitcoin-qt, all good there!

My concern is this, If I move a few BTC into individual 1BTC wallets, do I have to worry about any Change Address issues if I simply ignore them completely for a long time?  Assuming my private keys are kept safe over time, is there any way I can lose funds this way?  I do not plan on making further deposits into any of these wallets, if my funds grow I will keep another hot wallet or setup more cold storage.  I also do not plan on withdrawing funds at any time, when I do it will be a full sweep per wallet.

Before I proceed with sending my hard earned mining BTC to each address, I want to make sure I take all the proper precautions, any help from you BTC pros is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use multiple cold storage wallets, but either way, offline-generated keys and a full sweep upon spending is enough to keep your funds completely safe. When the time comes, don't try to "test" moving funds **out** of cold storage. Do the full sweep.
Also see this
[if my wallet is sufficiently secure, can I ever lose my coins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13843/if-my-wallet-is-sufficiently-secure-can-i-ever-lose-my-coins)

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by "full sweep"?

Comment: move the entire balance into another address, then never use the first address again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I feel better.  If I were to generate ONE address offline and use that for cold storage, can I use it to continually make deposits into it?  Without running a risk of a change address, etc?